# List of possible Android versions from settings for all Build.VERSION

Tags: android

I need to create a sign up page on our website to have potential beta testers sign up for testing. I would like to gather information about their phones to decide whether to use them so part of the sign up is providing their Model number and Android version from settings.

I'd like to provide a list of options for just the **Android Version** so they can just select the right one but I can't seem to find a list of possible versions.

We support versions 1.6 to ICS. Is there a list somewhere of the possible strings that get displayed for "Android version" in the settings?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [API levels documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html). It has a table with all major Android versions since 1.0.

Edit: I also found a [version list on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history) which seems complete *(to me at least; see comments)*.

Comment: Ops you're right, shouldn't have said all, thats an overstatement. All  I can see missing here are some versions of the 2.3. branch (e.g. 2.3.7.) though - out of curiosity: anything else missing I'm not aware of?

Comment: Nevermind, found quite a few, e.g. `3.2.x`. Android seems really more of a version mess than I thought before.

Comment: I'd suggest using the code name (Gingerbread, Honeycomb, Ice Cream Sandwich) name for the end user and using a web service to get exact information "under the hood".

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can find a complete list of model numbers. Different manufacturers can do whatever they want and there are more new Android devices every day. Also, there are lots of Android version numbers (examples taken from an emulator I happen to have open): the firmware version (e.g., "2.1-update1"); the Kernel version (e.g., "2.6.29-00261-g0097074"); the Build number (e.g., "sdk-eng 2.1-update1 ECLAIR 35983 test-keys").